# Viewing Debian documentation offline

Tags: debian, documentation

How do I read various manuals, guides and howtos, which are usually in the form of deb packages with names ending in `-doc` and installed in `/usr/share/doc` directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to install [doc-base](http://wiki.debian.org/doc-base) package, which registers all documentation that is not man pages or info files. Then you use one of the following packages - dwww, dhelp, doc-central, yelp, or khelpcenter4 - to view it.

Source: [Debian FAQ: What other documentation exists on and for a Debian system?](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/support.en.html#debiandocs)

Comment: Tried all those: `dwww` worked great instantly (but is browser based; I like CLI but that's another thing), `dhelp` didn't work (for example, not hit for "xclip"), "doc-central" didn't work (doesn't seem to be a tool - no command installed, just a folder with a homepage that displays two frames, one of which is dysfunctional), `yelp` worked (GUI), `khelpcenter4` didn't work with no trace whatsoever after `aptitude install`. Although `dwww` seems great, I'd like a CLI browser or emacs mode for this. As for `links`, `lynx` (@CarlosCampderrós below): a lot of those files are not in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

To see doc in html form (of the packages that provide it), you can install `apache2` on debian, and by default has an alias to `/usr/share/doc`, accessible only from `localhost`. So, install apache2 and then go to `http://localhost/doc/`.

Or you can use a text-based browser like `w3m` or `links` directly on the command line: `w3m /usr/share/doc/lintian/lintian.html/index.html`

Comment: The access control on Debian to .../dwww is done by /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/dwww.conf

Answer (score 0):

There is LOTS of documentation already on your GNU/Linux system, although except for man pages, some of it is fairly unfriendly.

I went looking for a browser for this stuff and am excited to finally have this documentation more easily at hand.

**Here are notes from two document browsers I've tried out:**

---

Both `dwww` and `doc-central` run as a web page.  I didn't try out [`dhelp`](http://www.fifi.org/doc/dhelp/dhelp.html) as it doesn't appear to be in my repository.

`dwww` seems to be much more advanced than `doc-central`, which now appears quite old.

`man -k dwww` shows you that it's actually quite complex, even including a cache, and cron jobs.

You may need to reconfigure your web server a bit as I had to to get these to work.

Also if you do try it out `doc-central`, the man page is at `man doccentral`, not `doc-central`, which is kind of annoying.

**Here are some screen shots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[debian-handbook](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/debian-handbook) , [debian-reference](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/debian-reference) , [harden-doc](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/harden-doc), [debian-faq](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/debian-faq) and other packages on: [Debian Users' Manuals](https://www.debian.org/doc/user-manuals.html), can be installed for offline use.

```
sudo apt install debian-handbook debian-reference harden-doc debian-faq
```